# Mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, technical

Is there a word that means "Mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive" (as an adjective) or "to be mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive" (as a verb), or is there a noun that describes some set as "mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive?"

For example,

> In a good multiple-choice survey item, the answer choices should [be] ____.

The term "[shattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shattered_set)" (e.g. the answer choices "shatter" the space of possible answers) was introduced to me as having this meaning, but I don't think that introduction to the term was quite right in accurately conveying the meaning - I now understand that it's a *family of functions* which can be said to "shatter" a set of points if some function within that family can exactly separate any subset of the points from the rest.

Answer (score 3):

You might try [Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set):

> a grouping of the set's elements into non-empty subsets, in such a way that every element is included in one and only one of the subsets.

It seems a bit awkward, but you might try...

> In a good multiple-choice survey item, the answer choices should *partition* the possible answers.

Comment: Yup, that's the answer.